# I2C and pullup resistors

Tags: raspberry-pi, i2c

I have a working EY88 10DOF IMU working on my raspberry platform without any pullup resistors. I have done some reading online and it states that pullup resistors are unquestionably needed?

1. Do I need a pullup resistor for the SDA and SCL lines?
2. Could this possibly increase data transfer speed?

Thank you
Misha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pullups are definitely required. I2C devices have open-drain connections to the bus, meaning that they can not drive a high signal, they can only drive it low or "release" it. The pullups are what drives the SDA/SCL signals high. See [Sparkfun](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/i2c/i2c-at-the-hardware-level)'s introductory article.

A couple of things could be at work here:

1. The accelerator/gyro is mounted on some type of evaluation board that has the pullups integrated.
2. The I/O lines on the Pi have internal pullups that are enabled.

Comment: ok understood. Thanks mills for your answer. So ultimately, if I understand it correctly, all I2C interfaces require pullup resistors. But in my case the pullups are integrated on the sensor chip/module as a whole, and hence no additional pullups required?

Comment: @Misha in short, if you got it working, then yes. I don't see how it could possibly work otherwise. PS. If you feel I've answered your question, please consider accepting the answer.

Answer (score 4):

[The Raspberry Pi has 1.8K pullups on the SCL and SDA lines.](https://pinout.xyz/pinout/i2c)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the total Cb (capacitive load -refer to each device's data sheet)  of your bus as well as the chosen i2c mode. Your raspberry's 1.8 KOhm resistors on the SDA & SCL lines might be enough.

Here is an [online tool](https://atman-iot.com/blog/i2c-pull-up-calculator/) for correctly sizing the resistors at different bus frequencies.